Centrality measures on bipartite graphs
It is possible to calculate Betweeness centrality on bipartite directed graphs? Something like this example:
Example graph
Intuitively I think it is impossible as the shortest path will always have only 1 edge. One important point is that the edges are weighted.
Thank you very much in advance.
